# How to check total percentages in a dataframe with each respective user id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataset containing almost 3 million csv files. Each csv represent different user.
First of all i have appended all the csv's together and assigned a userid to each of them.

Here's the preview of how i appended all of them into a single feather file

[CLICK HERE FOR HOW I APPENDED DATAFRAME 1 ALL CSV's into Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrzV8.png)

Here's a preview of dataframes

[CLICK HERE FOR Dataframe1 (K3) preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIkex.png)

[CLICK HERE FOR Dataframe2 (Questions) preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eogMa.png)

What i need is that a program should check a entry from column (item_id) (Dataframe 1 which is K3) and matches the entry from column(question_id) (dataframe 2 which is questions)and verify user_answer entry (Dataframe 1) is same as correct_answer (Dataframe 2).

If they match then it should create a new dataframe and stores the percentages.

For Example

Expected Output

[CLICK HERE FOR EXPECTED OUTPUT PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09aRL.png)

What i have tried so far is I can manually calculate each csv one by one to get this result but i cannot do one by one for over 3 million files. Thus i want is pandas to do go over through each user interaction

```
   counter = 0
for key, item_id in B['item_id'].iteritems():
    try:
        if B.loc[key, 'user_answer'] == questions.loc[questions['question_id'] == item_id, 'correct_answer'].values[0]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass  
    except Exception:
        pass


print(counter)

Total = len(pd.value_counts(B['item_id']))
InCorrect = (Total) - (counter) 
User_1_sucess = ((counter) / (Total) ) * 100
print (User_1_sucess)
User_1_failure = ((InCorrect) / (Total) ) * 100
print (User_1_failure)
```

Comment: Depending on how long your existing solution takes and how often you'll need to do this, another option may be to run it in a loop as it is... sometimes simple is best

Comment: @sabik : for my existing solution , I would've to write this program 3 million times.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to put a loop around it to go file by file

Comment: @Sabik, Can you please let me know how should i write that loop?

Comment: How long does it take? Is that number times 3 million acceptable?

Comment: How to write the loop - you don't show how you read the file your code; also, how are the CSV files identified, are they all in one directory?

Comment: @Sabik : I don't know how to write a specific loop for this.
Secondly : I have run my existing solution on a single csv file. It took around 4~6 minutes approximately for a single csv. 
I have to do this for 3 million csv's.  Processing that much isn't a issue I have a very powerful CPU & GPU.  it's just that I would have to write this solution for 3 million times to check one by one. I actually need a specific loop to do this but don't know how to write it

Comment: @sabik , Apologies , Kindly review it again I have posted a screenshot how i appended all of the csv's together and yes they all are in a same location

Comment: Right, if it takes 5 minutes each, doing it in a loop would be prohibitive. How big are these CSVs? 5 minutes is a lot!

Comment: You already have a loop; just instead of appending the dataframes, call a function to deal with each one in turn

Comment: I have a dedicated Powerful CPU and GPU as well which takes not more than a minute.  each csv is around 500 kilobytes ~ 1.0 Megabytes
just require the loop which would do this

Comment: Probably a good optimisation would be to put the correct answers into a `dict`; that's much faster to look up than searching through the whole answer sheet each time

Comment: Also, get rid of the `except Exception: pass`; you need to at least record which files caused errors, and ideally handle the errors individually

Comment: With 0.5-1 MB per file, that'd be 1.5-3 GB just to hold the combined dataframe in memory once, and it's a huge object to handle; since you don't need to cross-reference them, don't load them all at once

Comment: I mean, there are definitely ways to do this "properly" in pandas, with joins etc to check the answers; however, more straightforward code with `.iterxxxx` (as you started writing) will probably be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

One option, which doesn't really use the full power of pandas but may be more straightforward to code, would be to take the code you've already written, optimise it somewhat, then put it in the loop and apply it to each CSV file in turn

Something like (rough draft):

```
# make a dict of the correct answers, for speed:
correct_answers = {}
for _idx, row in questions.iterrows():
  correct_answers[row['question_id']] = row['correct_answer']

del questions  # optional, can help if memory is tight

results = []  # can be a dataframe instead
errors = []

all_files = all_files[:10]  # only process first 10 for testing

for filename in all_files:
  try:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, ',', index_col=None, header=0)
    user_id = filename.split('\\u')[-1].split('.')[0]
    print("Processing %s" % user_id)
  
    counter = 0
    for _idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['user_answer'] == correct_answers[row['item_id']]:
            counter += 1

    total = pd.value_counts(df['item_id'])
    results.append((filename, user_id, counter, total))
  except Exception as e:
    errors.append("Error processing %s: %s" % (filename, e))

  del df  # optional, can help if memory is tight

print("Results:", results)
print("Errors:", errors)
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote the solution but I get an error on this line 
 correct_answers[row['question_id']] = row['correct_answer']

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Ah, `.iterrows()` puts the index in; it needs to be `for idx, row in xxx.iterrows()` in both places. Let me fix that...

Comment: I simulated that code on demo dataset which only contains 10 csv's just to ensure if this will work or not.  any how I got processing error